# All product images need to be defined in view.xml?

Tags: magento2, cache, product-images, gallery-image

In Magento 2, the image sizes are defined in theme's `view.xml` file, e.g. in Luma theme: `/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/etc/view.xml`:

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
    <width>240</width>
    <height>300</height>
</image>
```

**But what if I create an image programmatically and the size is not defined in** `view.xml`?

For example, I need to display images of unusual size for different categories (based on configuration in admin panel). So I create an image like this:

```
$_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$imageId = 'product_base_image';

$customImage = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $imageId)
    ->constrainOnly(true)
    ->keepAspectRatio(true)
    ->keepFrame(false)
    ->resize(399, 399)
    ->getUrl();
```

1. If I create image like this, does it mean that my images will not be generated when I run command `bin/magento catalog:images:resize`? Does Magento only generate product images of sizes which are defined in `view.xml`?
2. Will my custom images be cached just like images which are defined in `view.xml`?